# Changing an input button to an image (alt text not showing) HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to swap out all my default submit buttons to image submit buttons. However, when I do this it still functions fine but there seems to be not text over the image like the `value="Login"` on the default button so my I was trying `alt="Login"` but it simply wasn't appearing. Anyone know why this is?

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
            <div id="userNameLoginDiv">
                <p>Username:</p>
                <input type="text" name="username" size="12">
            </div>  

            <div id="userPasswordLoginDiv">
                <p>Password:</p>
                <input type="password" name="password" size="12">
            </div>

            <div id="loginBtnDiv">
                <input type="image" src="IMAGES/button.png" alt="Login">
            </div> 
        </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because image inputs are server side image maps. They are designed to let the user pick a point on the image and send its coordinates to the server. The *image* itself is the information to be shown to the user, not some text.

The alt text is only shown if the image cannot be (e.g. if the URL to it is a 404 error or if the visitor makes use of screen reader software).

If you want a background image on a submit button, then use a submit button and set the `background-image` CSS property. (You may also want to set `border`, `padding`, et al).